# MongoDB C# Driver - 2 database hits instead of one when doing UPSERT

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, upsert

I am using the latest official C# wrapper for MongoDB (2.0.0).
(mongo db version v3.0.3)

My Model is:

```
public class MovieRent
{
    public int MovieCode { get; set; }

    public int RentStatus { get; set; }
}
```

My method updates the movie rent status, and if the movie dose not exists, it enters a new document (upsert):

```
public async Task UpdateMovieRent(MovieRent rent)
{
    var rents = _Database.GetCollection<MovieRent>("movierents");
    var builder = Builders<MovieRent>.Update;
    var update = builder.Set(m => m.RentStatus, rent.RentStatus);
    var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };
    await rents.UpdateOneAsync<MovieRent>(m => m.MovieCode == rent.MovieCode, update, options);
}
```

When looking on the trace info of the server (I run mongod.exe -v), I see two commands being executed.
The first one is:

```
update movies.movierents query: { MovieCode : "3" } update: { $set: { RentStatus: "1" } }
```

The second one is:

```
command movies.$cmd command: update { 
    update: "movierents", 
    ordered: true, 
    updates: [ 
        { 
            q: { MovieCode: "3" }, 
            u: { $set: { RentStatus: "1" } }, 
            upsert: true 
        } ] }
```

**This seems like a lot of db hits** (twice as much (-: ). as I can achive the same update with only one command via the mongo shell like so:

```
db.movierents.update(
    { MovieCode:"3" },
    { 
        $set: { RentStatus: "1" }
    },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

Which indeed result only one entry in the mongo trace, instead of two when using the C# driver.

Is this how the C# driver works by design or am I missing something here ?

Comment: What vesion of the server are you using?

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Using MongoDB 3.0, I see two lines when using the shell and the .NET driver. What's more, if you change from using $set to using $inc, you can prove to yourself only 1 is happening by ensuring that the value wasn't incremented twice.

Comment: I see only one line that has the WRITE attribute. there are some other lines, but they are connection start/end etc... What matters it that I see ONE write line . I am using RoboMongo to execute the shell command.

Comment: You seem to be asking a logging question. When you use the driver, if you change to a $inc instead of a $set, does the value get incremented twice or just once? This will prove whether 2 writes are actually happening or not. I can't speak to what Robomongo does, but it might not be using write commands and using old style op protocol writes, which probably result in just one line.